# Create entity that refers to an existing entity

Tags: clojure, datomic

I am able to create entities from existing Clojure data. However I am having trouble attaching existing entities to entities I am attempting to create. Where there is a `:ref :one` in the schema can I place an `eid` or a `:db/id`? I have tried both, but received back only error messages. In the following code the schema for `:statement/bank-account` is defined as `:ref :one` and the `read-account` function successfully retrieves an existing (bank) account entity:

```
(defn read-account [conn account-name]
  (let [db (d/db conn)]
    (d/q '[:find ?a
           :in $ ?an
           :where
           [?a :account/name ?an]
           ] db account-name)))

(defn make-statement [conn {:keys [bank-acct-name]}]
  (let [db (d/db conn)
        bank-acct-id (->> bank-acct-name
                          (read-account conn)
                          ;; (d/pull db [:db/id])
                          first
                          )]
    {:db/id                  (d/tempid :db.part/user)
     :base/type              :statement
     :statement/bank-account bank-acct-id
     }))
```

This code gives `IllegalArgumentExceptionInfo :db.error/invalid-lookup-ref Invalid list form: [17592186045426]  datomic.error/arg (error.clj:57)`. If I comment out the `first` I get exactly the same error message, which perplexes me. If I then un-comment the `(d/pull db [:db/id])` I get `IllegalArgumentExceptionInfo :db.error/not-an-entity Unable to resolve entity: :db/id  datomic.error/arg (error.clj:57)`.

EDIT In the process of getting this question answered I discovered that `eid` and `:db/id` are the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns a set of 1-tuples, e.g `#{[1] [42] [323142] ...}`

You'll want to change it to return only one value:

```
[:find ?a . ;; mind the '.'
 :in $ ?an
 :where
 [?a :account/name ?an]
 ]
```

For what this function does, you probably don't need to use pull - the eid on its own will suffice.

Comment: If the error message had not been the same whether passing in a set or vector, like if the error message had said 'don't pass in a set', then the error message from using `first` was 'don't pass in a vector', then I would have gone `ffirst` and not needed to ask this question at all!

Comment: Well, you would also have needed to use `ffirst` upstream of d/pull for it to work

Comment: `ffirst` in place of `first` worked fine, as in did not give an error message. This makes sense to me because the `eid` is in the vector. Nothing to do with the `pull` which is commented out and stayed that way for all but one experiment.

Comment: I made the comment more obvious. I don't know why SO hasn't syntax highlighted this code as Clojure, or if there's a way to help it...

Comment: To get syntax highlighting I tagged it as Clojure, which isn't ideal as I'm pretty sure only Datomic ppl would care to see this question.